# some database code does not work after I moved from win7 to win10

Tags: vb6

```
Dim WithEvents rs As Recordset
Dim db As Connection
Dim query As String
```

The `dim db as connection` gets the error "user defined type not defined".

I have many other applications with the same code that don't get that error and I have no idea why.

Comment: Do you have ADODB in the project references?

Comment: GSerg, yes 6 and 2.8

Comment: Pick one. Also, are there any `MISSING:` references?

Comment: GSerg, yes, it says the Microsoft access 12.0 object library is missing. However, the other programs I run don't have it included either and they work fine

Comment: There is a difference between not having a reference and having a broken reference. Uncheck MS Access.

Comment: GSerg - hey that worked. Thank you very much